# How do I get started removing this wood frame?

Tags: wood, windows, frame, demolition

[image: Photo of the frame]

This is a frame inset into this old leaded-glass window I'm going to restore. It is nailed into the original frame, and I can't get to any of the nail heads to get started. It's important that I don't damage the original wood, but the inset frame is junk.

Strategies?

Comment: Would need close ups of the area you need to remove to give a solution

Comment: There is a lot going on in your picture. Just what are you going to work on, the stained glass portion only. If so, then a picture of it only would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a reciprocating saw down the side of the frame an cut the nails. 
[image: reciprocating saw]
You could also cut the inside frame in sections, without hitting the original frame. Then just break it apart with a hammer an chisel

Or if you can find where the nail heads are just chisel around them (without hitting nails) an enough room to grab the heads with a pair of pinches. 
[image: pinches]

Answer (score 0):

Nailheads are inset into the frame you want to remove/get rid of?
A [Dremel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dremel) rotary tool, or similar, will quickly gouge the wood/filler around any nail holes so you can get at the nails themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're concerned about saving the wood... I can't tell from the photo, but I think I'd start by looking at whether I could insert a wedge or prybar behind it and gently lift the piece free; the nails will either come with it or (if they're trim nails) pull through it; the latter is easier to repair than most of the pry-the-nails-out-first solutions.

(I used a set of plastic wedges, followed by careful use of prybars, when disassembling a simpler windowframe last year. Wound up replacing all of that trim anyway since I decided I'd rather see oak than paint, but I could have reinstalled it if I'd wanted to.)